# Are Smash TV and/or Total Carnage able to be completed without continuing?

Tags: smash-tv, total-carnage

I've played the Midway arcade games "Smash TV" and the sequel "Total Carnage" many times both in the arcade and through console emulations/releases.  I have beaten both, but not without using dozens of lives.

I'm a competent game player, but while both games are challenging, my experience has been that they are "quarter consumers", with gameplay designed specifically to require many "continues" as opposed to rewarding a skilled player.

Are (non-tool-assisted) skilled players capable of minimizing continues (or even performing a 1-Credit Clear (1CC)) in Smash TV and Total Carnage, or do these games truly treat the player "unfairly"?  I prefer an answer to focus on Total Carnage, since it has been my experience that that game is much more challenging and less forgiving than Smash TV.

Comment: @Frank - I've revised the question.  Granted a "quarter eater" would be a game that treats a player unfairly, requiring players to continue inserting quarters instead of rewarding skilled gameplay.

Comment: That's why I commented; I haven't voted to close, but your title invited a subjective opinion.  Now that you're revised your title, the close votes may stop.

Comment: @Frank not really since the question now tends to ask why it was developed that way... which is off-topic. I doubt this question, for what it really wants to know, will ever be on-topic.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Hrm.  Missed that.  I was just going for a title change, as I thought the original body of it was answerable.  JoshDM, now, it might be straying too much into a "Why was it designed that way?" type of question, which is off-topic, I'm afraid.

Comment: It's not "why was it developed" that way, it is pretty much "is it possible".  Cloudymusic seems to have understood what the question was.  The rest of you are focusing too much on any portion of the opinion concept to put aside bias and determine the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are (non-tool-assisted) skilled players capable of minimizing continues in Smash TV and Total Carnage, or do these games truly treat the player "unfairly"?

Like most old arcade games, yes, these games are entirely possible to clear on one credit, given enough skill and practice. Here's a legitimate (non-TAS) 1CC playthrough of Total Carnage, for example:

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, though a supplemental one for Smash TV would be cool as well.  The game never felt like it could be completed on skill alone.  This player was talented, and to go it "alone" was crazy.

Comment: It can be hard to differentiate between TAS and non-TAS replays on YouTube (since a lot of casual TAS players have a habit of not stating that fact up front), so I unfortunately didn't come across one as conveniently as this.

Comment: I don't understand the abbreviation "TAS".

Comment: Sorry, tool-assisted (basically, played with savestates, slowdown, or other mechanisms to make the game easier). "TAS" literally means "tool-assisted speedrun," where the acronym originated, but it's commonly used as shorthand for tool-assistance in general. Generally, it can be hard to distinguish the two if you're not highly familiar with the game in question already, but lots of extremely short, twitchy micro-movements (as though they were done at a slower speed and then sped up) can be a telltale sign.